# CV Joint Overhaul - is it worth it?

Tags: transmission, steering

I have problems with one of my CV joints on my 1993 Acura. I read the repair manual and they suggest that actually fixing the joint itself is a pain and that most people should just buy a new axle shaft. Now, this car is kind of a beater so I don't want to spend too much money on it, and I have two options:

a. listen to the repair manual and buy a new axle shaft for somewhere around $60.
b. ignore the warning and get a CV joint boot kit for $10

Has any of you done a CV joint overhaul? Is is worth $50 to just not have to worry about it, or is the manual exaggerating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The boot kit alone isn't going to be enough to overhaul the joint - you might need parts of the actual CV joint if the boots have been open to the elements long enough for dirt to get in there and turn the grease into grinding paste. If you're at that stage, buy an overhauled axle shaft.

Comment: Ditto on the recommendation for a refurb piece, especially if it's a beater.

Comment: Also, most axle shafts I've seen come with a lifetime warranty, so if the CV joint wears out again, you pay $0 next time around.

Answer (score 3):

One can never monitor the axle boots frequently enough.  If you catch the boot leaking grease before it splits, the $10 solution will work.  If it is knocking and giving you trouble before you notice the direct opening to road grit, water and everything else, @Timo has the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on an F150 2001.

The CV axle was 60$ new.

A boot kit was 25$.

Much more value in just getting a new CV.  More work but then you know you won't have to get down there again (hopefully).

Answer (score -2):

Original Axles and CV Joint kits will always be better than remanufactured, they are just built to closer spec and balanced better.
That said, if you buy new CV joints to rebuild your Original axle there is only a 50/50 chance you will get it done right and it will be balanced well.
If you can find a good quality remanufactured axle then that might be the best option. Definitely don't go with the cheapest you can find just because they offer lifetime warranty.

Comment: Hey @gereonb, Welcome to the Mechanics Stack Exchange and thanks for posting your first answer.

I've down-voted this answer as it appears to be primarily opinion-based.
A focus on answering the primary questions would be ideal, and perhaps more information about why remanufactured Axles and CV Joint kits can be worse vs OEM, as that blanket statement certainly does not apply to all remanufactured parts of those types.

Comment: The very nature of “remanufacturing” means to take a used/abused part and refurbish it with used/new parts to make it similar to a new part, sadly the material tests and the fact that materials age makes these remanufactured parts always lesser quality than totally new original parts.
My answer was to recommend that the OP buys a good quality reman part rather than the cheapest reman part, this is a qualified answer based on 30 years of automotive experience and not just opinion.

Comment: Hey sorry I think I badly misread what you were saying there and was thinking more on the line of new parts by third parties. You're absolutely right that remanufactured parts are quite iffy.

A good thing to add to your answers is something mentioning that you are a qualified mechanic as it clears it up as not just an opinion.